# Designing Calendar table - datatypes

Tags: database-design, t-sql, datatypes

I'm in the process of designing the Calendar table. I took some inspiration from Database design book by Louis Davidson.

What I'm confused about are the data types.

Example:

```
MonthName varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Year varchar(60) NOT NULL,
Day tinyint NOT NULL,
DayOfTheYear smallint NOT NULL,
Month smallint NOT NULL,
Quarter tinyint NOT NULL,
```

I think the `Year` might be a typo, but not sure why it's `VARCHAR` when other numeric dateparts are of numeric data types.

But why is `Month` `SMALLINT` when it could be `TINYINT` as well?

I thought I should design table to use the smallest correct data type to save some page space (even insignificant).

On the other hand the `DATEPART` function in TSQL returns `INT` data type, so maybe I should make all the numeric columns `INT` to avoid conversion cost?

Answer (score 1):

From my view so far, Year field needs being as text one in some cases e.g. to support Chinese Year Name - this year 2019 is called 'Ji Hai'

But anyway, we should always have Year field as INT.